# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') In cpanel hosting

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, cpanel, inertiajs

I am facing an unwanted and odd problem in my project. It's showing in one of my module's main index pages, displaying the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name').

**In CPanel hosting**

I have already checked the casing (OK). I tried to create another module (similar problem). Have a laravel through relationship in parent model(company). It's fine on my local machine and creates; edit route works fine in the live server (also, I have similar crud, which works fine)

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return Inertia::render('Pesticides/Index', [
        'pesticides' => Pesticide::with('company')
        ->filter($request->all())
            ->sorted()
            ->paginate()
            ->withQueryString(),
        'query'  => $request->all(),
    ]);
}
```

**Model**

```
class Pesticide extends Model
{
    public function units()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
    }

    public function company()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function pesticideSale()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(PesticideSale::class);
    }
}
```

Please help.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel/PHP.  This is a problem in Vue. So please show us your Vue code

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that there was problem with my  mysql database.